# derivatives using epsilon-delta argument

Tags: calculus, general-topology, derivatives

I have this question below and am not sure if my approach is correct. Can anyone please advise me? Thanks.

Question: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and suppose there is a positive constant $K$ such that $||f(x)|| \leq K||x||^{5/3}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0=0$ and that $D_f(x_0) = 0$.

Working:
Given that $||f(x)|| \leq K||x||^{5/3}$,
we get $||f(0)|| \leq K||0||^{5/3}$,
hence, $F(0) = 0$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, must find $\delta > 0$ such that $||x-x_0|| < d \implies
||f(x) - f(x_0) - D_f(x0)(x-x_0)|| \leq \epsilon ||x-xo||$.

$||x||\leq \delta \implies ||f(x) - f(x_0) - D_f(x_0)(x-x_0)|| = ||f(x) - f(0) - Df(0)(x-0)||$

$= ||f(x) - D_f(0)(x)||$

$\leq||f(x)|| + || D_f(0)(x)||$

$\leq K ||x||^{5/3}+|| D_f(0)(x)||$

$= (K||x||^{2/3} + ||D_f(0)||) ||x||$

$< (K\delta^{2/3} + ||D_f(0)||) ||x||$

$< \epsilon ||x||$, where $\delta > ||(\epsilon-||D_f(0)||)/K||^{3/2}$
Therefore, $f$ is differentiable at $x_0=0$.

For $||x-x_0||<d$, and $x_0=0$,
the linear approximation is $f(x) = f(x_0)+D_f(x_0)(x-x_0)$

$f(x) = D_f(0)(x)$
as $x\rightarrow 0, f(x)\rightarrow f(0) = 0$
hence, $D_f(0)(x)=0$ for all $x$.
Therefore $D_f(0)=0$.

Comment: Please use latex http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Where did you find this problem ?